How to get promo code information for payment link
I am trying to get promo code information from payments in stripe. It could be either invoice, subscription or payment link. For subscription, I can get it from invoice.paid.
However for payment link, I am having a tough time to find promo code when its applied. The checkout.session.completed event does not have any information. Nor does the payment_intent.succeeded event have it.
Example of payment intent
{
  "object": {
    "id": "pi_3PekrdDLL6mQEvFD2z3EYfXH",
    "object": "payment_intent",
    "amount": 990,
    "amount_capturable": 0,
    "amount_details": {
      "tip": {
      }
    },
    "amount_received": 990,
    "application": null,
    "application_fee_amount": null,
    "automatic_payment_methods": null,
    "canceled_at": null,
    "cancellation_reason": null,
    "capture_method": "automatic_async",
    "client_secret": "pi_3PekrdDLL6mQEvFD2z3EYfXH_secret_8jdd9QUARxzFp7ywewyiQRQ9G",
    "confirmation_method": "automatic",
    "created": 1721511049,
    "currency": "usd",
    "customer": null,
    "description": null,
    "invoice": null,
    "last_payment_error": null,
    "latest_charge": "ch_3PekrdDLL6mQEvFD2SyHUWM2",
    "livemode": false,
    "metadata": {
    },
    "next_action": null,
    "on_behalf_of": null,
    "payment_method": "pm_1PekrdDLL6mQEvFDA0vSPPxG",
    "payment_method_configuration_details": null,
    "payment_method_options": {
      "card": {
        "installments": null,
        "mandate_options": null,
        "network": null,
        "request_three_d_secure": "automatic"
      }
    },
    "payment_method_types": [
      "card"
    ],
    "processing": null,
    "receipt_email": null,
    "review": null,
    "setup_future_usage": null,
    "shipping": null,
    "source": null,
    "statement_descriptor": null,
    "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
    "status": "succeeded",
    "transfer_data": null,
    "transfer_group": null
  }
}

This for checkecout.session.completed
{
  "object": {
    "id": "cs_test_b14uJHQgleFfeBD5YsOQdSXdC4WRGqQ2OGYm4q6ai704FjIkOem5rBF22G",
    "object": "checkout.session",
    "after_expiration": null,
    "allow_promotion_codes": true,
    "amount_subtotal": 1100,
    "amount_total": 990,
    "automatic_tax": {
      "enabled": false,
      "liability": null,
      "status": null
    },
    "billing_address_collection": "auto",
    "cancel_url": "https://stripe.com",
    "client_reference_id": "9PVT0AMJ",
    "client_secret": null,
    "consent": null,
    "consent_collection": {
      "payment_method_reuse_agreement": null,
      "promotions": "none",
      "terms_of_service": "none"
    },
    "created": 1721511033,
    "currency": "usd",
    "currency_conversion": null,
    "custom_fields": [
      {
        "key": "referralcode",
        "label": {
          "custom": "Referral Code",
          "type": "custom"
        },
        "optional": true,
        "text": {
          "default_value": null,
          "maximum_length": 255,
          "minimum_length": null,
          "value": null
        },
        "type": "text"
      }
    ],
    "custom_text": {
      "after_submit": null,
      "shipping_address": null,
      "submit": null,
      "terms_of_service_acceptance": null
    },
    "customer": null,
    "customer_creation": "if_required",
    "customer_details": {
      "address": {
        "city": null,
        "country": "US",
        "line1": null,
        "line2": null,
        "postal_code": "07310",
        "state": null
      },
      "email": "rrr2@rr.com",
      "name": "123",
      "phone": null,
      "tax_exempt": "none",
      "tax_ids": [
      ]
    },
    "customer_email": null,
    "expires_at": 1721597433,
    "invoice": null,
    "invoice_creation": {
      "enabled": false,
      "invoice_data": {
        "account_tax_ids": null,
        "custom_fields": null,
        "description": null,
        "footer": null,
        "issuer": null,
        "metadata": {
        },
        "rendering_options": null
      }
    },
    "livemode": false,
    "locale": "auto",
    "metadata": {
    },
    "mode": "payment",
    "payment_intent": "pi_3PekrdDLL6mQEvFD2z3EYfXH",
    "payment_link": "plink_1Ov62mDLL6mQEvFDOyqA0DLX",
    "payment_method_collection": "always",
    "payment_method_configuration_details": {
      "id": "pmc_1Ne5fgDLL6mQEvFDhq2LTqTH",
      "parent": null
    },
    "payment_method_options": {
      "card": {
        "request_three_d_secure": "automatic"
      }
    },
    "payment_method_types": [
      "card"
    ],
    "payment_status": "paid",
    "phone_number_collection": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "recovered_from": null,
    "saved_payment_method_options": null,
    "setup_intent": null,
    "shipping_address_collection": null,
    "shipping_cost": null,
    "shipping_details": null,
    "shipping_options": [
    ],
    "status": "complete",
    "submit_type": "auto",
    "subscription": null,
    "success_url": "https://stripe.com",
    "total_details": {
      "amount_discount": 110,
      "amount_shipping": 0,
      "amount_tax": 0
    },
    "ui_mode": "hosted",
    "url": null
  }
}

The only event that is created is customer.discount.created which has promo id but customer email is missing.
{
  "object": {
    "id": "di_1PekreDLL6mQEvFDshNIz6fe",
    "object": "discount",
    "checkout_session": "cs_test_b14uJHQgleFfeBD5YsOQdSXdC4WRGqQ2OGYm4q6ai704FjIkOem5rBF22G",
    "coupon": {
      "id": "D3muUbBu",
      "object": "coupon",
      "amount_off": null,
      "created": 1710630574,
      "currency": null,
      "duration": "once",
      "duration_in_months": null,
      "livemode": false,
      "max_redemptions": null,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "name": "williamette",
      "percent_off": 10,
      "redeem_by": null,
      "times_redeemed": 17,
      "valid": true
    },
    "customer": null,
    "end": null,
    "invoice": null,
    "invoice_item": null,
    "promotion_code": "promo_1Ov6MmDLL6mQEvFDcPVK9bfM",
    "start": 1721511050,
    "subscription": null,
    "subscription_item": null
  }
}

How do I get this information for payment link? Which event is the best to see if payment has promo code or not for any payment (subscription, invoice, payment link)

Discount details can be found under total_details.breakdown.discounts property. However, it's not included in Checkout Session object by default, i.e. checkout.session.completed event. A separate Checkout Session Retrieval request to expand total_details.breakdown property will be required to get discount / promotion code information.
For example,
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions/cs_test_xxx \
  -u "sk_test_xxx:" \
  -d "expand[]"="total_details.breakdown" \
  -G

